# How to use runOnUiThread() in alertDialog to change my textView using setText() method

Tags: android

I have been trying to change my `textView` text using `setText()` on **Done** button click from *Soft Keyboard*. But it wont work. I can set the text from anywhere else except for in the on button click. I am also able to set a working Toast from the Done button click, just can't cant manipulate the textView from inside. I was hinted that I should try `runOnUiThread()` method, but I still cant get it to work and I have spent hours trying. This is all from within a custom adapter if it makes any difference.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ID);
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        final AlertDialog OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();

        final MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();





        //makes textView clickable
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked
                //final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                // put aler dialog box logic here
                OptionDialog.setTitle("Enter new chore");
                OptionDialog.setView(input);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                //checks if "Done" button on soft keyboard is clicked
                input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                            //what happens when "Done" is clicked

                            //textView wont change to string hello
                            //textView.setText(input.getText().toString());
                            mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // your stuff to update the UI
                                    textView.setText("hello");

                                }
                            });



                            //this toast works
                           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                            //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            OptionDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });



                OptionDialog.show();
            }
        });


        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `onEditorAction` is already on UI tread. Why do you want to use runOnUiThread ?

Comment: I am not sure myself just a suggestion from an other stack overflow post.

Answer (score 0):

The line `final MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();` is wrong because the mainactivity already exist. Pass the reference of the calling activity to the arrayadapter and call `myactivity.runOnUiThread()`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Pass the reference of the calling activity to the arrayadapter" I am just learning.

Comment: When you call `new CustomAdapter()` you pass `Context` and `ArrayList`. Just add `Activity` to the constructor and pass it through.

Comment: How exactly would I add Activity to the constructor?

Comment: Your current constructor is     `public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }`

Now you have to pass your activity like that:

    `public CustomAdapter(YourActivity activity, Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
myActivity = activity;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't in a subclass of the `Activity`, so you may not use `runOnUiThread()` method because it is a method of `Activity`.

`final MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();` is not correct, you should never new an Activity yourself.

Instead, you can use `View.post(Runnable action)`, just like this:

```
input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //what happens when "Done" is clicked
            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your stuff to update the UI
                    textView.setText("hello");
                }
            });

            //this toast works
            // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
            //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            OptionDialog.dismiss();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't fix the problem for me. but I am getting these errors in log cat-

Comment: E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection